# Criteria query throwing limitations error with multiple orOperator

Tags: mongodb, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to query with multiple orOperator using Criteria.orOperator.But it is throwing some limitations error that we cant use or operator twice.

**Here is the query**

```
    Criteria criteria1 = new Criteria();
    criteria1.orOperator(Criteria.where("dumEmployeeId").is(user.getId()),Criteria.where("toDumEmployeeId").is(user.getId())).andOperator(
    criteria1.orOperator(Criteria.where("priority").is("Important"),Criteria.where("priority").is("Urgent")));
```

Here two conditions is compulsory.There are two fields.And in both fields i need to check with two different data.Thats why i am having **orOperator** for individual fields.And then i am appending these two fields with **and** operator.But it is throwing limitations error.Can anyone tell how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code.

```
Criteria criteria1 = new Criteria();
            criteria1.orOperator(
                    Criteria.where("dumEmployeeId").is(user.getId()),
                    Criteria.where("toDumEmployeeId").is(user.getId())).
                    andOperator(
                        new Criteria().orOperator(
                                Criteria.where("priority").is("Important"),
                                Criteria.where("priority").is("Urgent")
                        )
                    );
```

Comment: what happened was you used same criteria to create criteria which suppose inject to inside to outer criteria.