# Retrieve MongoDB documents based on two fields with OR condition in Java Sprintboot application

Tags: spring-mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with two documents like

```
{
"field1":"value1"
}
```

and

```
{
"field1":"value2"
"field2":"value1"
}
```

I want to retrieve both documents in my Springboot microservice.

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("field1").is("value1").orOperator(Criteria.where("field2").is("value1")))
List<Something> list = mongoTemplate.find(query, Something.class);
```

The above code returns an empty list whereas the below code returns the first document.

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("field1").is("value1"))
List<Something> list = mongoTemplate.find(query, Something.class);
```

How can I retrieve both documents?

Comment: Could you try to use the syntax from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51242834/492336 - i.e. like `orOperator(where1, where2)` instead of `where1.orOperator(where2)`.

Comment: Great, I posted it as answer, could you accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use syntax such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51242834/492336), i.e. like `orOperator(where1, where2)` instead of `where1.orOperator(where2)`:

```
Criteria criteria1 = new Criteria();
        criteria1.orOperator(
                Criteria.where("dumEmployeeId").is(user.getId()),
                Criteria.where("toDumEmployeeId").is(user.getId())).
                andOperator(
                    new Criteria().orOperator(
                            Criteria.where("priority").is("Important"),
                            Criteria.where("priority").is("Urgent")
                    )
                );
```